# Receiving not found error when registration process in SpringBoot app despite of correct URI

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

im in a very early developing of this app made in SpringBoot and Mysql with front of Angular , and trying to implement on my security process the register or creation of user , when i check on my swagger or postman i receive this json error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-11-03T17:53:58.048+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/login/renter"
}
```

On my humble logic that makes me think i got some miss-typed URI, but thats not the case.
Here some of the process

```
SECURITY CONFIGURATION

package com.example.demo.security;
....some imports....
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    RenterService renterService;

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                        "/register/renter",THIS ONE IS WHAT IM TRYING TO REACH AT
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login/renter")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .permitAll();
    }//permissions per endpoint

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(renterService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

}
```

For some reason just got me in the login page('login/renter'), not recognizing the url permitted formerly

Then my controller(In this case im trying to register a user thus the controller im exposing is the one referring to that process

```
REGISTER CONTROLLER

package com.example.demo.controller;
.....some imports....


@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    RenterService renterService;

    @ModelAttribute("renterCreated")
    public RenterRegisterDto renterRegisterDto() {
        return new RenterRegisterDto();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationFormRenter(Model model) {
        return "registration";
    }


    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "register/renter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("renterCreated") @Valid RenterRegisterDto renterCreated, BindingResult result) throws GeneralException {

        Role newRole = new Role();
        newRole.setRoleType("User");

        if (renterService.findByEmail(renterCreated.getRenterEmail()) != null) {
            logger.error("user with email" + renterCreated.getRenterEmail() + "is already registered");
            result.rejectValue("email", null, "There is already an account with this email");
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }

        renterService.save(renterCreated);

        return "userCreated";
    }
}
```

On my service literally trigger the process of creating a user , asigning it a role  and encryptying his password

```
RENTER SERVICE
public interface RenterService extends UserDetailsService {

    Renter findByEmail(String renterEmail) throws GeneralException;
    Renter findRenterById(Long id)throws GeneralException;
    Renter save(RenterRegisterDto registerDto);

}

RENTER SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION

@Service
public class RenterServiceImpl implements RenterService {
    @Autowired
    private RenterRepository renterRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public Renter findByEmail(String renterEmail) throws GeneralException {
        return renterRepository.findByRenterEmail(renterEmail).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("SNOT_404_1", "EmailNotFound"));
    }


    public Renter findRenterById(Long id) throws GeneralException {
        return renterRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("SNOT", "Id not found"));
    }

    public Renter save(RenterRegisterDto registerDto) {
        Renter renter = new Renter();
        Role role = new Role();
        renter.setRenterName(registerDto.getRenterName());
        renter.setRenterEmail(registerDto.getRenterEmail());
        renter.setRenterPassword(passwordEncoder.encode((registerDto.getRenterPassword())));
        renter.setRole(new Role(role.getRoleType()));
        return renterRepository.save(renter);
    }



    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String renterEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Renter renter = renterRepository.findByRenterEmail(renterEmail).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password."));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(renter.getRenbterEmail(),renter.getRenterPassword(),mapRoleUser(Arrays.asList(renter.getRole().getRoleType())));
    }


    private static List<GrantedAuthority> mapRoleUser(List<String> roles){
        List<GrantedAuthority>authorities=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String role : roles){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

And the RegisterUserDto class just would set the string variables referring every field of the sign up form neccesary in the process to be sent to the Back(i won't expose all the code cause is already too much )

As far as i could humbly understand guess the problem would be located in my controller registration process , specifically the endpoint , and its permission in the spring security congifuration(which by the way i double checked are the same url) reason why when i try to trigger the process aiming to that endpoint  pasing all the data automatically refuses it and send me to the login page with endpoint(login/renter)
Any idea about why is this happening?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is there a "/login/renter" endpoint?

Comment: You are right macedonboy.Thanks